# Supporting Vector images in the App which is remotely stored

Tags: xcode, ios8

Would like to know is it possible to incorporate vector images from a remote source in an app as of targeting both 2x and 3x. It has been told that .png files are generated in the run time for the particular vector in asset catalog. Appreciate your comments just to be clear on this fact.

https://www.createful.com/2014/using-vector-pdf-icons-xcode-6/

[How to programmatically put vector images in iOS asset catalog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27393473/how-to-programmatically-put-vector-images-in-ios-asset-catalog)

Thanks.